# XML Parsing Illegal XML character error in SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was running this query in SQL Server 2008 (10.0.5890), 
Collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

```
SELECT
   CAST(event_data.value('(event/data/value)[1]',
   'NVARCHAR(max)') AS XML) AS DeadlockGraph 
FROM
   ( SELECT
      XEvent.query('.') AS event_data 
   FROM
      ( -- Cast the target_data to XML SELECT
         CAST(target_data AS XML) AS TargetData 
      FROM
         sys.dm_xe_session_targets st 
      JOIN
         sys.dm_xe_sessions s 
            ON s.address = st.event_session_address 
      WHERE
         name = 'system_health' 
         AND target_name = 'ring_buffer' ) AS Data -- Split out the Event Nodes CROSS APPLY TargetData.nodes('RingBufferTarget/ event[@name="xml_deadlock_report"]') AS XEventData ( XEvent ) ) AS tab ( event_data )
```

But it was always ended with the following error:

```
Msg 9420, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 22203, character 102, illegal xml character
```

Even if I changed it to VARCHAR(max) it remains the same.
Though this same script was running fine and without any issue in another server with the same version & collation.

Sample XML result from the working database:

  
    
  
  
    
      
        
      
      
Proc [Database Id = 5 Object Id = 2033194789]

```
    </process>
    <process id="process55d288" taskpriority="0" logused="584" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594332250112 (6b0281c999d7)" waittime="1281" ownerId="1679" transactionname="EventGetQueueTopSp" lasttranstarted="2016-07-02T20:08:56.350" XDES="0x8209f990" lockMode="U" schedulerid="4" kpid="2880" status="suspended" spid="58" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2016-07-02T20:09:12.370" lastbatchcompleted="2016-07-02T20:08:59.090" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.090" clientapp="EventService Queue Check" hostname="WVERPDB" hostpid="3148" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" xactid="1679" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671221856" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="" line="96" stmtstart="8066" stmtend="8714" sqlhandle="0x0300050009a8007d9eadc300449e00000100000000000000" />
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
</deadlock>
```

Here is the SQL version for both DB

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5890.0 (X64)   Apr  2 2015 16:07:19   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (VM)
```

Comment: It is line 22,203 in the string that we need to see - not the line of code. Though actually seeing line 22,203 will be problematic in SSMS because of it's annoying habit of truncating long strings unless they are XML and given the nature of your problem. You might need to knock up a quick query in something like C# to retrieve the entire content of target_data to see this and find the offending character.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to find the "illegal" character:

1. There are two places in your query that cast to `XML`, so start with confirming which one is throwing the error. I doubt it is the outer `SELECT` since that is just taking a subset of the data that is already valid XML. And, if it was the outer CAST, that would mean that an *individual* deadlock graph would have at least 22,203 lines it. Most likely the error line number that is leading you to the outer select is simply referencing the query, not a particular part of the query.

   Remove the `CAST(` and `AS XML)` parts of the outer `SELECT`. If the error still happens, it is coming from the `CAST(target_data` part, else it really is the outer part. OR, you can just highlight and run the inner-most `SELECT` (i.e. the one that is the derived table, `Data`).
2. Next, we need to see the string that you are trying to CAST into XML. This is tricky as you can't display more than 64k characters in the Grid in SSMS, and using SQLCMD will get 1 million characters, but this data is likely well over even that limit.

   However, we can break it up into smaller pieces. As far as my testing shows, the fact that you have a line # in the XML that is above 1 indicates that there are newlines in the source value. So, we can capture the incoming `target_data` value from `sys.dm_xe_session_targets` and print it to the Messages tab of SSMS. Yes, the `PRINT` statement is limited to 8000 `VARCHAR` characters or 4000 `NVARCHAR` characters, but we can split up the original value on the newline characters and call `PRINT` on each chunk. I have the code for a Stored Procedure that does just this on PasteBin at [T-SQL Stored Proc to PRINT NVARCHAR(MAX) values](http://pastebin.com/4UBfFZRv), which is based on my DBA.StackExchange answer [How to output more than 4000 characters in sqlcmd](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97188/how-to-output-more-than-4000-characters-in-sqlcmd/97350#97350).

   Create the **DisplayN** Stored Procedure and then run the following query:

   ```sql
   DECLARE @ShouldBeXml NVARCHAR(MAX);

   SELECT @ShouldBeXml = st.[target_data]
   FROM   sys.dm_xe_session_targets st
   INNER JOIN   sys.dm_xe_sessions s
           ON   s.[address] = st.[event_session_address]
   WHERE  s.[name] = 'system_health'
   AND    st.[target_name] = 'ring_buffer';

   EXEC dbo.DisplayN @ShouldBeXml;
   PRINT N'-------------------------------------';

   SELECT CONVERT(XML, @ShouldBeXml);
   ```
3. Scroll on down to whatever line # is noted in the "XML parsing: line XXXXX" error message that is below the `------------` line in the "Messages" tab.

   If there is no obviously invalid character on that line (and you can try copying and pasting that line into a `SELECT CONVERT(XML, N'{that_bad_line}');` statement to test out to confirm), then we can modify the **DisplayN** Stored Procedure to also output the `VARBINARY` hex values of each line so we can find hidden / control characters.

Answer (score 1):

As wBob noted in the comments, there have been a few issues with the extended events XML output. You could update your servers and hope the issue is fixed in a more recent build.

However, you say that you are testing the query on another system and it's working fine, but you are trying to parse the extended events in the ring_buffer, which means it's from memory and you are not parsing the same XML.

I've had this happen, and there was actually a illegal character inside the XML, the only way I resolved that was replacing it with another one.

I don't remember what the character was but it was in the SQL Statement.

My best advice would be to have a good look at the XML using a good text editor and search for something in the SQL statements.