# Get the full text of a long request

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to get the full text of the request from the following request:

```
SELECT t.[text]
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS r
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) AS t
```

Here, with a sufficiently long request, the request text breaks off.
I use SSMS 17 and 18 versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be due to the **maximum amount of characters** that the result to grid can return, `65535`.

[image]

Starting from [SSMS 18.2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6126/sql-server-management-studio-18-new-features--high-dpi-support-and-2-mb-query-output-to-minimize-truncated-results/) you are able to change this.

Thanks [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand) for pointing that out.

[Aaron](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand) also mentions:

> if 64kb is the limit you’re hitting, there are a lot of places where
>   statement text is truncated long before that any way (see literally
>   any execution plan).

The text datatype of [sys.dm_exec_sql_text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sql-text-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is `nvarchar(max)`, no issues there.

**You could cast the column to XML as a workaround**

```
SELECT CAST(t.[text] AS XML)
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS r
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) AS t
```

Or a better method by [Evgeniy Gribkov](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/184982/evgeniy-gribkov)

```
SELECT t.[text] 
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS r 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) AS t 
FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS;
```

> Better this way: SELECT t.[text] FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS r CROSS
>   APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) AS t FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS;
>   Since the request text can not always be converted to XML. In
>   particular, it cannot convert query text when remotely calling stored
>   procedures: "XML parsing: line 13, character 129, illegal qualified
>   name character"

**Or save the results to a file**

[image]

Thanks [Erik Darling](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/32281/erik-darling) for linking some more [related answers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205720/how-to-retrieve-a-large-text-from-inside-a-table)

Comment: Better this way:

`SELECT t.[text]
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS r
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) AS t
FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS;`

Since the request text can not always be converted to XML.
In particular, it cannot convert query text when remotely calling stored procedures:
"XML parsing: line 13, character 129, illegal qualified name character"

Comment: @EvgeniyGribkov Great, my bad. You could add it as a separate answer or Ill add it to this answer, your choice :). Thanks

Comment: You can in [SSMS 18.2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6126/sql-server-management-studio-18-new-features--high-dpi-support-and-2-mb-query-output-to-minimize-truncated-results/), however if 64kb is the limit you’re hitting, there are a lot of places where statement text is truncated long before that any way (see literally any execution plan).

Comment: There are some related answers here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205720/how-to-retrieve-a-large-text-from-inside-a-table

Comment: It's also the last time @AaronBertrand was funny on the internet.

Comment: @ErikDarling I'm pretty sure I've told at least one dad joke since then.